# Implement MVVC for drill-down UITableview with Two type of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, model

I have a tableview which has a two type of cell. One with the image and other is usual one with text only. When user tab one of rows, tableview drill-down and opens a new tableview (like in settings on iOS). I had below data model but It works just for one page. How can I implement nested ones with MVVC. I searched lots of MVVC tutorials but can't figure out for my situation. I mean for example one row called "Documents" and when I tab documents, I want to list all documents like "First Doc", "Second Doc" etc and this procedure is same for all rows.

[Model Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n0pl.jpg)

```
protocol SameCell{
    var type: CellType { get }
}
struct LeftMenuSimpleCellData: SameCell{
    let cellText: String
    let haveIndicator: Bool
    let sub: subTable?
    let type: CellType
}
struct LeftMenuCarCellData: SameCell{
    let carImage: String
    let plateText: String
    let modelText: String
    let haveIndicator: Bool
    let sub: subTable?
    let type: CellType

}
struct subTable{
    let cellText: String
    let haveIndicator: Bool
}
enum CellType{
    case LeftMenuSimpleCellData
    case LeftMenuCarCellData
}
class LeftMenuDataModel{

    var optionsData: [SameCell] = []

    let carData: [LeftMenuCarCellData] =  []

    init(){

    }

func populateOptionsData(){
   optionsData.append(LeftMenuCarCellData(carImage: "icon", plateText: "Car", modelText: "Model Name", haveIndicator: true,sub: nil, type: .LeftMenuCarCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: false, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: true, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: true, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "HEllo", haveIndicator: true, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: true, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: true, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Hello", haveIndicator: false, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
    optionsData.append(LeftMenuSimpleCellData(cellText: "Exit", haveIndicator: false, sub: nil,type: .LeftMenuSimpleCellData))
}
```

EDIT: As I searched, "Key:Value" array can be work. But below code gives "LeftMenuSimpleCellData" does not conform to protocol 'Hashable' error.

```
var optionsData: [LeftMenuSimpleCellData: [LeftMenuSimpleCellData] ]?
```

EDIT 2: Can I just change struct to recursive one?

```
struct LeftMenuSimpleCellData{
let cellText: String
let haveIndicator: Bool
let subMenu: LeftMenuSimpleCellData
}
```

EDIT 3: I edited my code. It is working particularly now. But I haven't implement second sub menu yet.

Answer (score 0):

So according to your question and your comments , here is my final modified answer I have created a dummy `ViewModel` structure. Please take the reference of this and try to make your own ViewModel.
So Here we go....

```
    class LeftMenuSimpleCellData{
    let cellText: String
    let haveIndicator: Bool
    var nextVM : ViewModel?
    init(_ text : String , indicator : Bool = true ) {
        self.cellText = text
        self.haveIndicator = indicator

    }
}
class ViewModel : NSObject
{


    private override init() {
    }
    init(data : [LeftMenuSimpleCellData])
    {

        self.cellData = data
    }
    private var cellData = [LeftMenuSimpleCellData]()

    var count : Int {return cellData.count}



    func cellData(at index : Int) -> LeftMenuSimpleCellData {
        return cellData[index]
    }

}
```

Now for getting `RootNode ViewModel` , I have written this function

```
func getVM(for detail : [[String : Any]]) -> ViewModel {
        let leftCellMenu = detail.map {[weak self] (det) -> LeftMenuSimpleCellData in

            let leftCellData = LeftMenuSimpleCellData.init(det["name"] as! String)
            if let arr = det["Sub Menu"] as? [[String : Any]] , !arr.isEmpty {
                leftCellData.nextVM = self?.getVM(for: arr)
            }
            else
            {
                leftCellData.nextVM = nil
            }
            return leftCellData
        }

        return ViewModel(data: leftCellMenu)
    }
```

**Here is the dummy data for** `detail : [[String : Any]]`

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Wi Fi",
    "Sub Menu" : [
      {
        "name" : "Wi Fi1",
        "Sub Menu" : [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "Wi Fi2",
        "Sub Menu" : [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "Blutooth",
    "Sub Menu" : [
      {
        "name" : "Blutooth1",
        "Sub Menu" : [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "Blutooth2",
        "Sub Menu" : [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "General",
    "Sub Menu" : [
      {
        "name" : "About",
        "Sub Menu" : [
          {
            "name" : "Name",
            "Sub Menu" : [

            ]
          },
          {
            "name" : "Network",
            "Sub Menu" : [

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "Accessibility",
        "Sub Menu" : [
          {
            "name" : "VoiceOver",
            "Sub Menu" : [

            ]
          },
          {
            "name" : "Speech",
            "Sub Menu" : [
              {
                "name" : "Speech Selection",
                "Sub Menu" : [

                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This will give me a rootVM for mainViewController.

Now `mainViewController tableView` datasource method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let subMenu = vm.cellData(at: indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = subMenu.cellText
        cell.accessoryType = subMenu.nextVM == nil ? .none : .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
```

And for `tableView` delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let subMenu = vm.cellData(at: indexPath.row)
        guard subMenu.nextVM != nil else {
            return
        }
        let mainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        mainVC.vm = subMenu.nextVM!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: true)
    }
```

I hope now this will help you to achieve what you want. Please do comment if you have any query.

Comment: I understand your answer but what If I have a two sub-menu? I mean can I design it more dynamic like [Settings: [Detail] ] so that whenever detail has also a new sub-menu I can add it?

Comment: Or just recursive one like Struct A{ let subMenu: A }

Comment: Can you show me your model response? that will help me to think about it.

Comment: @EmreO. I have edited my answer. Please follow that.

Comment: It is a clever way but I have a more than two sub-menu. I mean for example wifi and bluetooth on iOS settings menu and they all have different sub-menus. In your answer, as I understand correctly, It works for wifi -> wifi name -> third sub?

Comment: Okay I got your problem. Wait, I am editing my answer.

Comment: @EmreO. Now I have modified my whole answer. I guess it will be helpful.